# Converging sequence implies limit point

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

Is it true that if a sequence in a metric space converges to a value, then that value is a limit point of the set of all terms in the sequence?

> $E = \{ p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n , \dots \} \subset X$, where $X$ is some metric space. Say $ \left( p_n \right)_1^\infty$ converges to $p \in X$. Then $p$ is a limit point of $E$ or in other words, every open ball about $p$ has an element, different from $p$, in $E$.

Convergence of the sequence means $$ \forall \varepsilon >0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: n \geqslant N \implies d(p_n, p) < \varepsilon \ . $$

Fix an arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$. Then we can always pick the open ball of radius $2 \varepsilon$ about $p$ which contains the point $p_n$. So every open ball about $p$ will have an element in $E$. But how can we be sure that $p_n \neq p$?

I suspect the hypotheses lack something and some extra requirement needs to be added e.g. $p_n \neq p$ for every $n \geqslant 1$. So the result may not be as general as expected?

Comment: It could be $p_1=p_2=...=p$.The sequence needs infinitely many entries different from $p$.

Comment: Right, so just like I wrote $p_n \neq p$ for every $n \geqslant 1$. Well there ya go, ty m8

Comment: @riverchristmas: $p_n\ne p$ for all $n\ge 1$ is sufficient, but it’s stronger than you need. All you actually need is that the set $\{n:p_n\ne p\}$ be infinite.